# How to use built-in webcam with Photo Booth on Mac OS X Mavericks 10.9?

Tags: mac, osx-mavericks, webcam

Photo Booth says “there is no connected camera.”  Where is a list of hardware? System preferences does not seem to have any such comprehensive list.

**Upddate**   Other applications were not able to use the camera either. The answers about "some application taking over the camera" turned out to be correct.

Comment: Well I figured out the answer and noted as such. But apparently the question/answer are not considered quality. Then fine, delete them.

Comment: Your question and answer are not that bad. I would consider editing your question to improve it, was it just photo booth that had problems? As to your answer, how did you find out that hangouts was the problem?

Comment: @Mokubai  Ok I added details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google hangouts was apparently monopolizing the camera - even though I had shut down the hangouts window.  I shut down Google-Chrome and at that point the camera became usable again in Photo-Booth. Note that I had installed hangouts only recently. I did not find a relevant post about Google hangouts not properly releasing the camera.

Answer (score 1):

Can any other app see it? Try QuickTime Player, new video recording Cmd/opt/n

Or try Apple menu   > About this Mac > System report > Camera & see if it's recognised